# Did Noah's family still have Original Sin?

Tags: original-sin, flood-of-noah

From what I understand, God created Adam and Eve, banished them from the garden, and humanity became corrupted and stained with Original Sin.

Some time passed. God said enough was enough, and started over with the great flood and Noah's Ark. The flood killed everyone on earth except Noah and his family and a pair of each species of animals on earth.

The idea of "starting over": Does it mean that Noah's family didn't have Original Sin anymore? Or did they still?

If they still had Original Sin, was it really starting over in the eyes of God? If they lost Original Sin, how did humans get it back?

I'm kind of confused on this part of the story. I'm not necessarily looking for bible quotes, just a simple explanation.

Comment: I think it would help if you could explain where you got the idea of "starting over", and what exactly is meant by that. It is not a normal idea to say that Noah's family was freed from original sin.

Comment: You have the order of operations wrong.

Comment: lol you put this on hold almost 4 years later? and you delete all the answers? You must spend all day and night trolling this site editing/deleting to fit your narrative. Sounds about right.